# Interacting with a simple database in c++?

Tags: c++, database

I'm making a game in c++ that will need to store and retrieve information about players (name, email, high score) etc. I thought of trying to just do it myself with XML but I think a real database (maybe SQL?) would do a better job since over time there may be thousands of users.

Are there libraries to do simple interactions with databases like queries, retrieving information, and storing information?

Thanks

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Yes, [SQLite](http://www.sqlite.org/) will do exactly this. It stores the database as a local file, so if you want an online database server then this is perhaps not the best option.

Comment: Users will connect to a server which will be running on a PC then the server will read the local file, and return the information to the user to ensure security.

Answer (score 4):

It sounds like `sqlite` might be a good fit for you. It doesn't need a constantly running database server, and it does things smarter than hand-rolled xml-serialization.

Sqlite has [documentation](http://www.sqlite.org/cintro.html).